# How do I call this external JS file in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS by decomposing code samples and putting them together in different ways.  **What specific changes need to be made to [the code in this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/mk7GwJC99IaUt0pafPgb?p=preview) so that code from an external script can be called from the `index.html` view?**

The code is from [this tutorial](https://hello-angularjs.appspot.com/helloworld), and the change that I want to make is simply moving the JavaScript code to an external JavaScript file that is called from inside the view.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First I changed the scripts tags to be like in the example you linked to.

Second, I added `ng-app="helloApp"` attribute to the html tag, so the helloApp angular module you defined will run on the html element (instead of not running at all).

Third, and lastly, I changed `Calvin Hobbes` on line 42 to be `{{name}}`, so it will be binded to the $scope.name var in your controller, instead of being a regular static text.

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aBj3Ih70FxhuYRLOiHTq) is a working example.

Comment: Thank you and +1 for answering the question on the level on which it was asked.  I do not know why some else down voted your attempt to promote learning.